# Can installing URL Rewrite 2.0 on production IIS 7.5 have a negative impact?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, rewrite

We have a Windows 2008 R2 server with IIS 7.5 and a lot of customer websites. Being no sys-admin but a developer, I hate to touch that wonderfully running system.

However, I'd like to update the IIS plugin *URL Rewrite* to version 2.0 via Web Platform Installer.

I do not want to do anything that might compromise the server, hence the question: can I expect it to work with at least a 99% chance? I did not find any bug reports or reviews on the web, so I'd like to hear an expert on that.

An educated guess will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never had a problem with updating it.  However, all precautions should be taken when doing so.  Below are a few:

1. Take a backup, a full backup and system restore point, backup your customer files too (btw, you should already be doing this anyway)
2. Schedule a maintenance period, let your customers know the server may be offline for a few minutes late at night one night.
3. A restart may be required, at the very least IIS might need to be reset.

Often, any update or install to IIS will require the web server to reset or restart the box in general.  Check the release notes for the new version, many times they list this in there.

Other than those things, have at it.  URL Rewrite is pretty stable, just review the release notes prior to installation.

Comment: Thanks Brent, that feels good. Of course we are backing up our files, but still a crash will be an annoyance. If someone had written "well, the update occasionally kills the IIS integrity", I'd reconsider running the update at all. So, good to know you never had a problem.

Comment: I should add, you need to check if any of your sites have rewrite rules in place, make sure they are compatible or need to be changed to work with the latest version.

Comment: Thanks again. I already updated the tools and did exactly that. Everything went like charm.